# different initializ and sign pointer value in global and function

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I know I will get many down grade regarding this question, but I still write following test code:

```
int *gPtr;
//I know I can NOT write below code line, but I need know WHY
gPtr = NULL;//or some other value which I want to init it
//int *gPtr = NULL; //this line should be OK

int main (void)
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The global `*gPtr` during compile will output error:

```
ptr.c:4:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
ptr.c:4:1: error: conflicting types for ‘gPtr’
ptr.c:3:6: note: previous declaration of ‘gPtr’ was here
ptr.c:4:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

However, in the function, I did same code, but no compile error/warning, I would like to know:

- what is the different between sign a value in global and function.
- why compiler do NOT allow me sign value in global area.
- what is different between `int a = 0;` and `int a; a=0;//no other code between these two sentences`

please give me advise for above three questions according to the compiler view(or you think it should have other explanation in some others view like coding standard?)

Comment: `int *gPtr = NULL;` and since it is static, just `int *gPtr;` will suffice. You can't; have programatic code stmts in global space like that. You *can* in a function. Fwiw, my compiler spits an entirely different error ("Type specifier required for all declarations").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a global variable with an initial value:

```
int *gPtr = NULL;
```

But you cannot do an assignment *outside of a function scope*.
The compiler (well, at least my clang compiler) actually interprets

```
gPtr = NULL;
```

in the global scope as

```
int gPtr = NULL;
```

which causes similar warnings and a conflicting types error:

```
warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
gPtr = NULL;
^~~~
error: redefinition of 'gPtr' with a different type: 'int' vs 'int *'
note: previous definition is here
int *gPtr;
```

Global variable without an explicit initial value are automatically initialized
to zero, therefore in your case

```
int *gPtr;
```

would be sufficient (as @WhozCraig already commented above).

Comment: +1 What ver of clang are you running. My 3.3 just whines about a missing type specifier. Just curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The one that comes with Xcode 5.0.2: Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Comment: Do you mean even I write `*gPtr = NULL` in global it actually same as I write `int *gPrt = NULL`?

Comment: @HowChen: What I mean is that `int *gPrt = NULL` is the same as `int *gPrt` for a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* int *gPtr; */
/* gPtr = NULL; */
int *gPtr = NULL;

int main (void)
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect you had one of two problems. Firstly, you can't declare `gptr`, then assign NULL to it, and *then* do a `int *gptr = NULL` (which does the first two combined); hence I commented out the first two. You need one or the other. Secondly your line `int *gPtr = NULL;` was missing a semicolon.

Comment: I think he knows this, he just wants to know *why* the first two lines don't do the same thing.

Comment: Difficult to tell but he appeared to be complaining about the compile error.

Comment: Ah I see what you are getting at. Yes, upvoted the other answer!